# If I second a seconder, what am I doing? Am I "thirding"?

Tags: single-word-requests, grammar, verbs

Say three people A, B and C are talking, with B and C agreeing with A.

> A: I think tomatoes are great.
>   B: Yes, I *second* this.
>   C: I *third* (?) it.

I think the obvious way to say this would be using *second* again:

> C: I *also second* this.

However, since we have the verb [to second](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/second?s=t), do we also have a verb to express this *seconding the seconder*? I see that [third](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/third?s=t) can be an adjective, a noun or an adverb, but not a verb.

Comment: If you also agree with the first one, then you are thirder. If you `second` the seconder, you are just seconding since you are approving of the second person and not the first one?

Comment: As your own research points out, *third* is not used in that sense. Whether you choose to support the person who originally said something (in which case you too are *seconding* them, as in your revised 'C') or the person who seconded the first one, you are still only *seconding* someone. Probably the best is to say, "Me too" in 'C' (also informally "+1" on internet/messaging platforms).

Comment: The usage probably overlaps with duelling, in which (according to Wikipedia) a participant could have several "seconds"

Comment: you simply say "I **support** the motion". That's all there is to it.  Nothing else to see here.

Comment: "I think the obvious way to say this would be using second again:" if you think that, you're wrong.

Comment: @JoeBlow could you expand on why saying _I also second this_ is wrong?

Comment: @fedorqui there can only be one "second" (in the literal sense of "number two") Even if you abstract "seconder" to mean "motion supporter" there's really only one "seconder" ("motion supporter") in most/all organisational/parliamentary systems.  "Thirder" is just a stupid joke, so forget that.  The answer is nothing more than "support" ("I support the motion.")  Note indeed that the definition of "seconder" is, indeed, "the first person to support the motion".  Indeed you need never use the word "second", just stand and say "I support that".

Comment: @JoeBlow note that _to second_ is currently used in more contexts than the one you describe. I do use _second_ and suggesting to just circumvent its use is not convincing me :)

Comment: HI @fedorqui *"note that to second is currently used in more contexts than the one you describe"*  Sorry, I don't see that.  It's only used in the procedural-parliamentary sense.  Even if people use it casually (say, "where for lunch??") it's the same process. If you're pointing out that people use "thirdly!!" as a stupid joke, so, I just typed that in the previous comment. You'd have to explain to me how you see it being used in "other" contexts.  Cheers buddy

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The term *second* in this context comes from the language of formal organisational processes.

> **Second** *verb*
>   1 Formally support or endorse (a nomination or resolution or its proposer) as a necessary preliminary to adoption or further discussion: *Bridgeman seconded Maxwell’s motion calling for the reform*
>   [- ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/second?q=seconding#second__29)

Here is a more descriptive explanation in the context of parliamentary procedure, but it also holds for other formal meetings:

> In deliberative bodies a second to a proposed motion is an indication that there is at least one person besides the mover that is interested in seeing the motion come before the meeting. It does not necessarily indicate that the seconder favors the motion.
>   [- wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_(parliamentary_procedure))

In this process, someone *proposes* a motion, and if someone else *seconds* it, the motion may be discussed and voted on. If there is no seconder, the motion isn't even considered.

There is no requirement for a 'second seconder' or a 'thirder', and no formal term for such a role. The term *seconder* is now used in informal settings to indicate agreement, with *thirder* sometimes used for further supporters.

> **I third that**
>   In response to "I second that," when you also agree with a person who is agreeing to something. 
>   [- Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=I%20third%20that)

If you wish to use less informal language, you can say that you *support* the motion or statement.

> **Support** *verb*
>   2.2 Give approval, comfort, or encouragement to: *the proposal was supported by many delegates*
>   [- ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/support)

Comment: I second this, @Lawrence! Let's see if there are any *thirders* and so on :)

Comment: I also second this, even though the usage of _to second_ has grown and it is used in more contexts than the one you mention. For example, find here where my question came from: [I second (third?) the idea of listening to books](http://productivity.stackexchange.com/a/3661/17932)

Comment: @fedorqui Thank you. I'll expand my answer to include this.

Comment: Thanks! So _to third_ is a valid word? Wow, this triggers me to ask: and _to forth_ and so on?

Comment: @fedorqui It's at least *well established* in colloquial usage, following the familiar 'first, second, third, fourth, etc' progression. However, in my experience, it's something intended to elicit a wry smile or similar, rather than something said in earnest. Nevertheless, the notion of strong support is also often present.

Answer (score 0):

#1. Statement of ORIGINAL PURPOSAL scenario: "This is that"

#2. Statement of the FIRST person that supports "this is that" IS the FIRST TO "Second IT" therefore IS the Seconder.

#3. Statement to "second it" can ONLY be stated ONCE, and ONLY by the first supporter.
All else in support of the ORIGINAL purposal or anyone "Thirds it" or Beyond, are ALL SUPPORTERS, saying so in their perspective Lango.

#4. ONLY if the first supporter to "second it" , adds to, takes away or changes the ORIGINAL purposal, can someone else "second it"... and by doing so, is in support of the "take away, add to or change", to and of,  the ORIGINAL PURPOSAL.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).